# Sort table by sub-string

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, substring

I'm trying to sort a table by course number, but I need to use a substring to sort by number. The course name looks like CX-001 for example, I wanting to ignore the first three characters. I'm using Vanilla Javascript. I'm not sure where to apply the substring, but I know I got it wrong.

```js
function sortSubNum(subNum) {
  var switchcount = 0;

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable2").substring(2);
  var switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  var dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    var rows = table.rows;
    var shouldSwitch;
    for (var i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

      var x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[subNum];
      var y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[subNum];
      //var resX = x.substring(2);
      //var resY = y.substring(2);

      if (dir === "asc") {
        if (Number(x.textContent.substring(2)) < Number(y.textContent.substring(2))) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir === "desc") {
        if (Number(x.textContent.substring(2)) > Number(y.textContent.substring(2))) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount === 0 && dir === "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
sortSubNum(1);
```

```html
<table id="myTable2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Teacher</th>
      <th>Course Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>CS-301</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>CX-201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Park</td>
      <td>CS-001</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of implementing your own sorting method directly on the DOM, consider initializing an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of elements and calling [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), then reinserting the newly ordered elements back into the table. It would be a lot faster and less error-prone.

Comment: I will keep this In mind for the future, I just solved my problem on my own by making a few adjustments.

Comment: @JamesParker You can answer your own question.  This way it could be a help to find this in the future.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty thanks for pointing that out. I'm a bit new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed substring from var table. Also, I changed conditionals in the for loop from

```
if (Number(x.textContent.substring(2)) < Number(y.textContent.substring(2)))
```

to

```
if(x.textContent.substring(2) < y.textContent.substring(2))
```

---

```
function sortSubNum(subNum) {
    var switchcount = 0;

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
    var switching = true;
    // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
    var dir = "asc"; 
    /* Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done: */
    while(switching){
        switching = false;
        var rows = table.rows;
        var shouldSwitch;
        for(var i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i ++){

            var x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[subNum];
            var y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[subNum];
            //var resX = x.substring(2);
            //var resY = y.substring(2);

            if(dir === "asc"){
                if(x.textContent.substring(2) < y.textContent.substring(2)) {
                    //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }else if(dir === "desc"){
                if(x.textContent.substring(2) > y.textContent.substring(2)){
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(shouldSwitch){
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount++;
        }else{
            if (switchcount === 0 && dir === "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you already found problem in your code but my solution is based on  @Patrick Roberts suggestion given in comment.

> Instead of implementing your own sorting method directly on the DOM, consider initializing an Array of elements and calling Array.prototype.sort(), then reinserting the newly ordered elements back into the table. It would be a lot faster and less error-prone

```js
function sortTable(tbody, col, asc){
    var rows = tbody.rows;
    var rowsLen = tbody.rows.length;
    var arr = new Array();
    var i, j, cells, cellLen;
    // fill the array with values from the table
    for(i = 0; i < rowsLen; i++){
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    cellLen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
        for(j = 0; j < cellLen; j++){
          arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    //short the array
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
       //this is your use case.sort the data in array after spilt.
       var aCol=a[col].split("-")[1];
       var bCol=b[col].split("-")[1];
       return (aCol == bCol) ? 0 : ((aCol > bCol) ? asc : -1*asc);
    });
    
    for(i = 0; i < rowsLen; i++){
        arr[i] = "<td>"+arr[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
    }
    tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>"+arr.join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr>";
}
var tbody=document.getElementById("myTable2Tbody");
sortTable(tbody,1, 1);
//for asc use 1,for dsc use -1
```

```html
<table id ="myTable2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Teacher</th>
            <th>Course Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id ="myTable2Tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>CS-301</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>CX-201</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Park</td>
            <td>CS-001</td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this. I like this approach

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution using `Array.sort`

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('#myTable2 tbody')
var trs = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')

var sorted = [...trs].sort((tra, trb) => {
    var courseA = tra.querySelectorAll('td')[1].innerText
    var courseB = trb.querySelectorAll('td')[1].innerText

    return courseA.split('-')[1] - courseB.split('-')[1]
})

tbody.innerHTML = '';
sorted.forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr))
```

```html
<table id="myTable2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Teacher</th>
            <th>Course Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>CS-301</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>CX-201</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Park</td>
            <td>CS-001</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```